# Allow access to my microsoft list or excel in onedrive only via powerapps

Tags: database, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have an application with powerapps
It uses connections to onedrive and sharepoint lists as databases.
Now, when I publish the application to other users in my organization, I have to share my list and excel data with them.
The problem is that I want them to be able to read and modify the list via powerapps and they can't access the list directly in sharepoint.

How can I do this?

I don't know if it is possible, because I cannot see option to allow only the app to interact with the list by not to share the list with other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because powerapps only works with the rights of the logged-in user. So you have to enable those users to make this work. You could hide the list but the user still has to have the correct rights if you want your powerapp to change the list.
Otherwise, you could go the more complicated path and write an external program from which they can change what you want them to change in the list and only have one user with those rights. Honestly, I wouldn't recommend that method since it is super complicated and comes with a load of it's own bugs. Had to do something like that for my organization and it was a pain to get that running properly. I am still working on some bugs on that...

Comment: So in your opinion, what is the best way to do that? I can't allow a user to modify data outside my Powerapps application.

Comment: just give the rights to only one user and write your powerapps application to trigger when a file is changed or so. And in this file you enter the data to be changed. You can use an application to enter data in, so your colleagues don't have to enter the data in a data format like json.

Comment: The file has to be in your onedrive though and only one colleague would be able to change the file at a time, except if you use something like a queue or so that applies the changes one by one at a time. However, this would require you to make the code run in steps and you have to implement it in a way where the application knows when it can enter new data